# Besides First Class Functions and Lexical Scoping, what does JavaScript share with Scheme implementations?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I have always wondered why Douglas Crockford keeps comparing JavaScript to Scheme. Yes JS was intended to be Scheme by its designer; but besides the first class function support and the lexical scoping (broken), what features does JS have in common with Scheme that makes it "Lisp in C's Clothing"?

Comment: Is there really a meaningful, definitive answer to this question?

Comment: @Pointy: Yes any feature beside first class function and lexical scoping would be a meaninglful and definitive answer. Do you know of any?

Comment: If you're wondering why Doug does something, why not send Doug an email?

Comment: @Ken : I didn't want to reply to such flippant reply but I want to point out that it is not about why Doug does what he does but if the thesis is a correct one and if you have a meaningful suggestion to take sides.

Comment: [This blog post](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2013/07/18/javascript-isnt-scheme/) is probably relevant here.

Answer (score 6):

Another thing that comes to mind is the pervasive use of a single ubiquitous data structure throughout the language and the libraries: *cons lists* in the case of Scheme, *maps* (called *objects*) in the case of ECMAScript.

Then there is not just the fact that ECMAScript has first-class procedures, but that those procedures are the *only* abstraction mechanism. (Or more precisely *encapsulation* mechanism.)

Comment: What about `(let)` in Scheme?  Well I guess ES5 will get that too.

Comment: @Pointy: You mean ES6? Yes, AFAIK, `let` is already in ES-Harmony. Basically, `var` is going to be abandoned, and is replaced with `let` (properly lexically scoped) and `const` (cannot be rebound).

Comment: @Pointy, `let` is just a syntax sugar. You can do the same in js: `(function (x) { ... })( ... )` instead of `(let ((x ...)) ...)`.

Comment: @SK-logic well yes I understand that, but it's a little more than just sugar; instantiating a function object is somewhat costly. (Of course, I suppose that creating a new scope via "let" might be non-trivial too.)

Comment: @Pointy, I believe that any decent functional (or nearly-functional) language compiler or interpreter must optimise these trivial application cases out, so it should be safe to resort to a function application. I'll check how V8 perform in such cases...

Answer (score 6):

One thing that should be high on this list is having a REPL.  Seems like a technicality, especially when these repls are usually hidden behind some "developer tools" thing, but it has a huge effect on the language.  (For example, it's natural to have a real `eval` when there's a repl, etc.)  It basically puts dynamic evaluation of code have first class status, which is extremely useful for something like JS, and probably has contributed much more to its success than first class functions (which really were hardly used until a few years ago).

Comment: Wow, I missed the elephant in the room.  This is obviously related to other features (runtime inspection, eval, no explicit compilation), but arguably more important that any of them individually.

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head, plus glancing at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29#Distinguishing_features):

- Block structure
- Runtime inspection
- Eval
- No (explicit) compilation step
- Small but rich stdlib
- Shared namespace for procedures and variables

Answer (score 0):

Well, JavaScript lacks [***homoiconicity***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconic), and this is one of the main properties of Lisp dialects.